# Adding variables to alerts in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I would like to use the same alert condition in a pine script for several stocks in TradingView.  The problem is that I won't know which stock triggered the alert unless I create copies of the script and have a custom message for each script.  I would like to have something like:

```
alertcondition(someCondition, title='Bullish', message=tickerid)
```

where I use the tickerid variable which is one of pine scripts built in variables.  However, when I attempt this, the message I get is literally tickerid instead of the tickerid of the chart associated with the script.  Is there any way to dynamically generate the tickerid?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'd like to know how to console.log variables in pine-script.

Comment: No.  I don't think that it's actually possible, so I'm using the ccxt library to grab the info my self and do the TA myself outside of trading view.

Comment: Interesting. I'd like to be able to port some of the amazing work by the Trading View community into Go, or Javascript. Have you found a way to determine whether the TA you are accomplishing with ccxt is equivalent to the trading view scripts? It's a little crazy, that logging does not exist in pine.

Comment: I can't speak for all of the indicators as I literally just got started (hence the recent question!).  However, so far things look like the match up when I use  ccxt with TA-lib.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, message of alertcondition cannot be dynamic at the moment. First, 'tickerid' is a function that is executed on a server side. Second, the alertcondition message is an entity that does not go to the indicators server engine. It's a static text message that should be displayed when alert triggers. This is how it works, hopefully it will be improved in the future releases.

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled upon your question just now and in case anyone else does too: Adding variables to the `message` of an `alertcondition` has been possible for a while. For example:

- `{{exchange}}`
- `{{ticker}}`
- `{{close}}`
- `{{volume}}`

([source](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/introducing-variables-in-alerts-14880/))

PS Kodify.net has a thorough tutorial on this: https://kodify.net/tradingview/alerts/alert-variables/