# How to add variables to an alertcondition when your condition is a security?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'm trying to create alerts with variables. I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48530411/adding-variables-to-alerts-in-pinescript) and [this article](https://kodify.net/tradingview/alerts/alert-variables/), but I believe because my condition comes from a Security function, I'm having problems with creating the alerts.

```
s01 = input('DOTSDT', type=input.symbol)
screenerFunc() => triggerA and triggerB
c01 = security(s01, res, screenerFunc())
alertcondition(c01, title="ALERT!", "Look at " + S01)
```

If I try the above, I get a:

`Cannot call 'alertcondition' with arguments (series[bool], title=literal string, message=input string)`

If I try the following...

```
alertcondition(c01, title="ALERT!", message="Look at: {{ticker}}")
```

...I get a

`Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function.`

---

**UPDATE**

In fact, the issue seems to be using the security function as a condition for alertcondition rather than the use of any variable. I've tried to simply use a static message, but still get the same error `Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function.`

**UPDATE!!!**

I've created [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65863553/alertcondition-fails-when-the-condition-comes-from-a-security-function), hopefully a more clear one:
[“alertcondition” fails when the condition comes from a security function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65863553/alertcondition-fails-when-the-condition-comes-from-a-security-function)

Appreciate your help :-)

Comment: Currently, the string variable cannot be added to the alert. Leave a feature request with TradingView via their support ticketing system. I think it is possible to add a placeholder {{label}}

Comment: @AnyDozer I don't understand. My issue is the condition. So do you mean it doesn't accept a string variable as a condition? Even if in this case my variable returns a boolean? (the return of the screenerFunc() is a boolean)

Comment: I realized that there are two questions. It is problematic to help without your script with an error in the condition, but even if you eliminate this error, the issue with the variable message in the alert will remain open.

Comment: If it is not possible to lay out the entire script, try to make a full fragment with an error that should work.

Comment: See also my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825212/pinescript-use-text-variable-in-alerts)

Comment: @AnyDozer I'm sorry for the poor formulation in my question  I've created a (hopefully) better question, where I also have a link to the entire code. Thank you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65863553/alertcondition-fails-when-the-condition-comes-from-a-security-function

Comment: Now it can be done. New alert features are [here](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/our-new-alerts-allow-for-dynamic-messages-22588/)

Comment: @AnyDozer Thank you so much for letting me know, I really really appreciate it! I've just updated the code. Cheers! https://github.com/42piratas/misc/blob/master/tradingview/screening_gridbots.pine