# "alertcondition" fails when the condition comes from a security function

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'm trying to create alerts based on conditions that derive from security functions.

Below, the relevant piece of the code, and [here is the entire code](https://github.com/42piratas/misc/blob/master/tradingview/screening_gridbots.pine).

```
s01 = input('BINANCE:BTCUSDT', type=input.symbol)
screenerFunc() => triggerA and triggerB
c01 = security(s01, res, screenerFunc())
alertcondition(condition=c01, title="Alert", message="Alert!")
```

But I'm getting the following error for the last line:

```
Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function.
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems in the code, the first, the function `screenerFunc` must combine all the strings to calculate the condition, the second, in calculating the range. Strings
with drawing lines are also commented out, since I don't know for which ticker they are relevant.

```
//@version=4
//42quants.com
//@42piratas

study("Grid Bots Screening", overlay=true)

// INPUTS

res = input(type=input.resolution, defval="60", title="Resolution")
lookBack = input(title="Lookback", type=input.integer, defval=24, minval=2)
range = input(title="Upper & Lower Range %", type=input.integer, defval=25, minval=10)

screenList  = input(false, "═════════ Screening ════════")
s01 = input('BINANCE:BTCUSDT', type=input.symbol)
s02 = input('BINANCE:ETHBTC', type=input.symbol)
s03 = input('BINANCE:XRPBTC', type=input.symbol)
s04 = input('BINANCE:LTCBTC', type=input.symbol)
s05 = input('BINANCE:BCHBTC', type=input.symbol)

s06 = input('BINANCE:LINKBTC', type=input.symbol)
s07 = input('BINANCE:ADABTC', type=input.symbol)
s08 = input('BINANCE:DOTBTC', type=input.symbol)
s09 = input('BINANCE:BNBBTC', type=input.symbol)
s10 = input('BINANCE:XLMBTC', type=input.symbol)

s11 = input('BINANCE:SNXBTC', type=input.symbol)
s12 = input('BINANCE:XMRBTC', type=input.symbol)
s13 = input('BINANCE:EOSBTC', type=input.symbol)
s14 = input('BINANCE:XEMBTC', type=input.symbol)
s15 = input('BINANCE:WBTCBTC', type=input.symbol)

s16 = input('BINANCE:TRXBTC', type=input.symbol)
s17 = input('BINANCE:XTZBTC', type=input.symbol)
s18 = input('BINANCE:COMPBTC', type=input.symbol)
s19 = input('BINANCE:FILBTC', type=input.symbol)
s20 = input('BINANCE:MKRBTC', type=input.symbol)

// INDICATORS & VARIABLES

var upperLimitLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.red,  width= 3, extend=extend.none)
var lowerLimitLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.black,  width= 3, extend=extend.none)
var upperRangeLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.blue, width= 2, extend=extend.none)
var lowerRangeLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.green, width= 2, extend=extend.none)

var range_corr = 100/range // the error was here

screenerFunc() => 
    
    highestHigh = highest(high, lookBack)
    lowestLow = lowest(low, lookBack)
    
    xAxisStartsAt = bar_index[lookBack]
    xAxisFinishesAt = bar_index
    
    upperLimit = highestHigh
    lowerLimit = lowestLow
    
    upperRange = highestHigh - ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range_corr) 
    lowerRange = ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range_corr) + lowestLow
    
    HighAboveUpperRange = high > upperRange
    LowBelowLowerRange = low < lowerRange
    
    occurrencesAboveTotal   = sum(HighAboveUpperRange ? 1 : 0, lookBack)
    occurrencesAboveSecondHalf = sum(HighAboveUpperRange ? 1 : 0, lookBack/2)
    occurrencesAboveFirstHalf  = occurrencesAboveTotal - occurrencesAboveSecondHalf
    
    occurrencesBelowTotal   = sum(LowBelowLowerRange ? 1 : 0, lookBack)
    occurrencesBelowSecondHalf = sum(LowBelowLowerRange ? 1 : 0, lookBack/2)
    occurrencesBelowFirstHalf  = occurrencesBelowTotal - occurrencesBelowSecondHalf
    
    // SCREENING
    
    triggerA = occurrencesAboveFirstHalf >= 1 ? true : false
    triggerB = occurrencesAboveSecondHalf >= 1 ? true : false
    triggerC = occurrencesBelowFirstHalf >= 1 ? true : false
    triggerD = crossunder(low, lowerRange)
    
    triggerA and triggerB and triggerC and triggerD

c01 = security(s01, res, screenerFunc())
// c02 = security(s02, res, screenerFunc())
// c03 = security(s03, res, screenerFunc())
// c04 = security(s04, res, screenerFunc())
// c05 = security(s05, res, screenerFunc())

// c06 = security(s06, res, screenerFunc())
// c07 = security(s07, res, screenerFunc())
// c08 = security(s08, res, screenerFunc())
// c09 = security(s09, res, screenerFunc())
// c10 = security(s10, res, screenerFunc())

// c11 = security(s11, res, screenerFunc())
// c12 = security(s12, res, screenerFunc())
// c13 = security(s13, res, screenerFunc())
// c14 = security(s14, res, screenerFunc())
// c15 = security(s15, res, screenerFunc())

// c16 = security(s16, res, screenerFunc())
// c17 = security(s17, res, screenerFunc())
// c18 = security(s18, res, screenerFunc())
// c19 = security(s19, res, screenerFunc())
// c20 = security(s20, res, screenerFunc())

// PAINTBRUSH

// line.set_xy1(upperLimitLine, xAxisStartsAt, upperLimit)
// line.set_xy2(upperLimitLine, xAxisFinishesAt, upperLimit)

// line.set_xy1(lowerLimitLine, xAxisStartsAt, lowerLimit)
// line.set_xy2(lowerLimitLine, xAxisFinishesAt, lowerLimit)

// line.set_xy1(upperRangeLine, xAxisStartsAt, upperRange)
// line.set_xy2(upperRangeLine, xAxisFinishesAt, upperRange)

// line.set_xy1(lowerRangeLine, xAxisStartsAt, lowerRange)
// line.set_xy2(lowerRangeLine, xAxisFinishesAt, lowerRange)

plotchar(screenerFunc())

// ALERTS
alertcondition(c01, title="Alert", message="Alert!")
```